# why won't this method work?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

this is probably a very simple correction that I cannot see but I'm pretty sure you guys can help me, this section of the code is supposed to read what the user inputs 1-12 (for a month of the year) and add one to the array location (i.e. if a user inputs 3 to the array then it will increment 'space' 2 in the array by one to tally the amount of occurences so to speak.), this code just goes through without any action taking place and gives the usual build successful after doing nothing.

anyway, I was hoping someone could give me a few pointers on where I'm going wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BirthMonth {

    public static void main(String[] args){                               
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int months [] = new int [12];    
    }

    public static int[] inputMonths(int[] months, Scanner input){

        System.out.println("please enter the first month with a birthday:");
        int month = input.nextInt();
        months[month - 1] ++;
        //arr[i] = Input.nextInt();

        while (month != -1){
            System.out.println("please enter the next month to be tallied");
            month = input.nextInt();
            months[month - 1] ++;
        }
        return months;               
    }
}
```

Comment: Rhetorical question: is `java.util.Scanner` only ever used in homework exercises?  Has anyone ever actually used it for something real?

Comment: ...So you do realize that you need to call inputMonths in your main method, correct?

Comment: Your indentation was quite strange before it was fixed, you should make sure you keep it consistent, your code will be much easier to read.

Comment: @skaffman: My OOP teacher in junior year taught us only java.util.Scanner. All class exercises were a variation of java.util.Scanner.

Answer (score 9):

You have to call your `inputMonths` method in your main method... ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your main method you're not calling your method `inputMonths(int[] months, Scanner input)`. So, your program won't do anything except creating the array and initialising the scanner. You have to add the call in your main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){                               
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int months [] = new int [12];   
        inputMonths(months, input) 
    }
```